# How do you manage ASP.NET Core authorization in a large project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, authorization, identity, roles

I am writing an intranet site for internal use at work using ASP.NET Core 2.2 & it already has many pages for displaying & updating information with more on their way. **It's been asked that almost every page has view, edit & delete permissions.** For authentication I'm using the built in *Identity* with *SQL Server* & you need to be logged in to see any more than the home or login page.

While it seems excessive, I planned to add roles for each level for every page & asign them to users as neccesary.

**Is there a better way to manage this?**

**Is there a reason to NOT do it this way?** (besides resulting in a stupid number of roles)

Comment: Would having one role mean you get the other? Aka is it more of a level or role, like view > Edit > Delete, so if you have the Edit role you can View it and if you have the delete role you can Edit it?

Comment: @George I'd quite like the result to work like that yes. Bits of ui or code will only display/run after a boolean check if the user has the appropriate role. To make it work as a level then something that requires edit permissions would do two checks for if the user has the edit role OR has the delete role. Something that needs the delete permission would only check for the delete role. I hope I worded that clearly.

Comment: Well to help with that you could use [role claims and authorise against that](https://benfoster.io/blog/asp-net-identity-role-claims) rather than the role itself which solves that issue of checking multiple roles. As for if it's the best way to manage it, it really depends how much you want to write on top of `identity`, if you don't then yes it's the best way and to my knowledge the only reason I can see to not do it this way is the amount of roles you'll have

Comment: How many distinct unique pages do you foresee the project having?

Comment: @joey roughly 100 to begin.

Comment: How many pages max would you estimate before the project is replaced with a new solution?